# Remove sublists from list while iterating

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I want to count number of elements and remove some if they meet a criterion. Removing using collect and removeAll doesn't work since it removes all equal elements and I want to remove a range not all. 
I tried to use sublist.clear() but I get ConcurrentModificationException even though I'm using it.remove().

```
public static List<Integer> controlOccurrences(List<Integer> sortedArr, int m) {
    int writelndex = 0, count=1;
    List<List<Integer>> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i < sortedArr.size(); ++i) {

        if (sortedArr.get(i-1).equals(sortedArr.get(i))) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if(count == m) {
                int nCopies = Math.min(2,m);
                List<Integer> c = sortedArr.subList(writelndex + nCopies, i);
                toRemove.add(c);
            }
            count = 1;
            writelndex = i;
        }
    }

    Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator = toRemove.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        List<Integer> integers = iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        integers.clear();
    }
    return sortedArr;
}
```

EDIT: adding an example:
Lets say we have the following list: (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5) and m = 3. This means that all numbers that occur m times should occur 2 times  (Math.min(2,3)). So the expected result is (1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5).

EDIT 2: @ShubhenduPramanik Solved the task very elegantly.
However, it's still unclear to me why ConcurrentModificationException was thrown even though I was using iterator.remove() and how would you go about removing a sublist from a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @Mansuro 1.8. I'll be happy to hear about a solution in newer versions as well.

Comment: @Mooshstv Your question is not clear. Pls give a sample input and expected output.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik I added an example, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
    static List<Integer> controlOccurrences(List<Integer> sortedArr, int m) {
            //make the count of each element
            Map<Integer, Long> result = sortedArr.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));


            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry : result.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue() == m) {
                    // Here 2 is hard coded. You can make a variable and pass it to the method with a parameter
                    for (int i = 0; i < m - 2; i++) 
                    {
                        sortedArr.remove(entry.getKey());
                    }
                }
            }

            return sortedArr;
        }
```

***N.B:*** This code is not perfect as I've assumed that `m>=2`

Comment: Very elegant thanks.
I still don't understand why in my solution I got the exception, can you clarify that?

Answer (score 2):

**If I correctly understood the task then the algorithm**:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int m = 3;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int numbers;

        List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Fill in the list with values
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            numbers = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            sortedList.add(numbers);
        }

        System.out.println(controlOccurrences(sortedList, m));

    }

    public static List<Integer> controlOccurrences(List<Integer> sortedArr, int m) {

        int count= 1;


        for (int i = 0; i < sortedArr.size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < sortedArr.size(); j++) {

                if (sortedArr.get(i).equals(sortedArr.get(j)) && i != j) {

                  count += 1;

                }

            }

            if (count == m) {
                sortedArr.remove(i);
                count = 1;
            } else {
                count = 1;
            }

        }

        return sortedArr;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Mooshstv Always happy to help

Answer (score 2):

To get the most optimized solution, you should:
1. Build a list (or set) of the indices of the values to remove
2. Move values of your original list to a new one, except the one at the listed indices.
3. Return the new list.

This way, your algorithm complexity is O(2n), which is more optimized than both previous answers. Plus, you keep given list untouched (which can be recommended  according to your execution context). Last advantage, the copy is favored because each remove call on a list is potentially heavy (inner objects after removed index are moved to the left: partial hidden browsing -_- )

I won't directly give you a working code, to let you practice ;).

Note: your use-case is too complex for it, but you should look at List.removeIf() code of array list API, which is really well optimized. Here is an article talking about it: [advantages of removeIf method](https://dzone.com/articles/the-way-of-the-lambda-and-removeif)